# Как вывести html-код текстом

Tags: javascript

При таком выводе в фрейме рендерится  полностью страница, как сделать что бы был только текст.

```js
    function displayFileContent(){
        fetch(filePath)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                var iframe = document.getElementById('contentContainer');
                iframe.srcdoc = data;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Нужно с сервера нормально передать данные

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В плане "нормально"

Comment: В плане передавать оттуда текст, а не всю страницу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне по условию нужно спарсить "штмл"-файл и вывести его в фрейм. Судя по вашим советам, мне попытаться преобразовать  полученные данные в "строку" и потом её вывести?

Comment: что возвращается с бэка? html-разметка?

Comment: @Meth0d да, мне нужно вернуть html-разметка

Comment: посмотрите в логах что в response. если там разметка - уберите response.text(), все должно работать.

Comment: не использовать `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

```
    function escapeHTML(str) {
    var map = {
        '&': '&amp;',
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;',
        '"': '&quot;',
        "'": '&#039;'
    };
    return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}

function displayFileContent(){
    fetch(filePath)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('contentContainer');
            iframe.srcdoc = escapeHTML(data);
        });
}
```

Comment: выглядит(есть) как костыль?

Comment: Нет. Это не костыль, а корректное решение задачи. Но, если ваша задача локальная, а не для "прода", то можете упростить себе жизнь тегом `<xmp>` вместо функции. Вот так `iframe.srcdoc="<xmp>${data}</xmp>"`. Учитывайте, что тег объявлен устаревшим, хотя практически все браузеры его и по сей день поддерживают.  С учётом того, что это коммент, пришлось заменить правильные кавычки на `"` (лапки). Разберётесь.